# The .To function in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

`this.onePX.To = 64;`

With the XAML:

```
<Rectangle Width="32" Height="32" Fill="Black" x:Name="onePX" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
```

but for some reason, it returns with:
`System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle does not contain a definition for "To" and no extension method "To"`...

Any idea why this could be happening, I tried to Google it, but searching for ".To" doesn't exactly yield accurate results ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Silverlight Rectangle does not have a "To" member (or method etc), so the compiler is quite right.

What are you actually trying to do the the Rectangle? That might result in better answers.

### Edit 2

Ok, if you want to move a rectangle (on a pixel basis I assume as you said to an X,Y coordinate) you 1st need to parent it under a Canvas. Only a canvas renders children on a pixel basis.

Secondly to actually move a child of a Canvas, you need to set the attached properties Canvas.LeftProperty and Canvas.TopProperty.

You can either do this using the static methods *Canvas.SetLeft(onePX, newValue)* and *Canvas.SetTop(onePx, newValue)* (which take the child object and new values as parameters), or you can use the other SetValue syntax which looks like *this.onePX.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newValue)* and *this.onePx.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newValue)* etc.

The first static-method syntax is usually shorter and easier on the eyes :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the quick response. I'm trying to move the Rectangle to a specific X,Y co-ordinate.